# Get returned id from angularjs promise

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to get back a new ID of a saved record, then save that id into an array to another object.  However, the ID never comes back in time or does as undefined.  Im pretty new to angular and firebase and have the current code so far.
Service:

```
 function addNewOffer(uid, offer) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        offers = $firebaseArray(firebaseDataService.offers);
        offers.$loaded().then(function (data) {
            offers = data;
            offers.$add(offer).then(function (ref) {
                var offerid = ref.key;
                console.log("added record with id " + offerid);
                deferred.resolve(offerid);
                return deferred.promise;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        })
    }
```

Controller:

```
 var offerid = offerService.addNewOffer(vm.userid, vm.offer);
        console.log(offerid);
        vm.transaction.offers.unshift(offerid);

        //then save transaction here
```

console says offerid is undefined.  So, then making the transaction not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. You need to grab the promise. The first function is the resolve function, the second is the reject function where you handle the error response from addNewOffer().

```
offerService.addNewOffer(vm.userid, vm.offer).then(function(offerid) {
  console.log(offerid);
  vm.transaction.offers.unshift(offerid);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

You should also move the return statement outside of the success handler in your main function:

```
function addNewOffer(uid, offer) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    offers = $firebaseArray(firebaseDataService.offers);
    offers.$loaded().then(function (data) {
        offers = data;
        offers.$add(offer).then(function (ref) {
            var offerid = ref.key;
            console.log("added record with id " + offerid);
            deferred.resolve(offerid);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Otherwise you won't have a value until the firebase promise is resolved.

Comment: i just tried that, and get TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, hmmm

Comment: See the additions to my answer from @ruedamanuel (thanks for the edit!)

Comment: Thank you sir, that indeed did fix my problem.  I also moved the save transaction code in the 'then'.

Comment: No problem. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Since the AngularFire API returns promises, there is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer`

Promises are chained by using a `return` statement in the success handler. Rejections are chained by using a `throw` statement.

```
function addNewOffer(uid, offer) {

    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    var offers = $firebaseArray(firebaseDataService.offers);
    promise = offers.$loaded()
      .then(function (data) {
        var offers = data;
        //return promise to chain
        return offers.$add(offer);
    }).then(function (ref) {
        var offerid = ref.key;
        console.log("added record with id " + offerid);
        //deferred.resolve(offerid);
        //return deferred.promise;
        //return promise to chain
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        //deferred.reject(error);
        //throw to chain error
        throw err;
    });

    return promise;
}
```

**Controller**

```
   var offeridPromise = offerService.addNewOffer(vm.userid, vm.offer);

   offeridPromise
     .then(function(offerid) {
        console.log(offerid);
        //vm.transaction.offers.unshift(offerid);
        //then save transaction here
        return offerid;
   }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
   });
```

> ### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since **a promise can be resolved with another promise** (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Srevice API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)